script run with gnu parallel needs to know which file it should work on
Given these csh commands:
set ARR = `echo $x $homeDir $pdbID $ligID $ligNum $dirName $cutoff` 

parallel -j 20 myParallelScript.csh "$ARR" ::: *.pdb

how can I grab the pdb file that was assigned to each one of the 20 commands and pass that filename to myParallelScript.csh
I have access to all the arguments in the ARR variable but not the name of the file that they will be applied to.
added {} before "$ARR" and was able to find the file used in each instance

I imagine you want to insert {} before ::: but it would help if you clicked [edit] and showed the first two full commands you want executed, including the parameters to each.

Try parallel --dryrun. Show what you get. Show what you wanted instead.

Thank you Mark for the now obvious missing argument in my original command.
